# What's the difference between these two different formats of binary data?

Tags: binary, data-formats

I'm naive on the subject of binary data, so I'm confused why I think of binary data as this:

```
1010011010100101010001010011111001011110101000111001110001010101110110000011010000110110001101010111101011111010101001011010010111010011110111001100011000110011000110010011001100010101010000001110101001110010011110110110000101010111001101110110011111100101010010110010011010110111010001100110111110111111100011011011001101110011110100111000011010011010111111011100100111001111111101011001001100011011011001100111111110111111110100101011001011101110111110100101110101110010011101001100111101101111101001100001011110010001010110000110000001100111100001110011100111
```

when I also see people refer to this as binary data:

```
067207af41f4a7b01b40c9c5440e08033d7d69fbc2e5738c7b526812ee0a8aab80807d6808b81d0fae29490c0601ebc9cd27cabcf200345dec1beb61f903a8fa526f201000e4d26fe40cf07da8daac0f3c7b53e51dd0f45c8c8c669e220c4107071d4d363da8bb5738ed4ec9604f61ed4b5b82b88abb587cb839c6e14a54293ce3de90124f5e2
```

What's the difference?

Comment: The first looks like a bit-by-bit representation, the second like a hexadecimal representation, ie each character represents 4 bits (0 == 0000 to F == 1111). These are just two of the common ways to represent binary data.

Comment: @fvu thanks. I see now.